# How to get information from link with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I searched a lot but I couldn't find a solution can you help me

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="click" href="#" data="new">New product</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="click" data="sale">Sale product</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="click" data="trent">Trend product</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tabspane"></div>
```

1. I want to pass data="new" , data="sale" and data="trend" information between `<li>` tags with ajax on every click.
2. I want data new to be active when it is not clicked.

I tried a few times, but I was unsuccessful:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav-link').click(function() {
    var datas = $(this) attr("data");
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: 'indextab.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { datas: datas },
    success: function(datal) {
      $('.tabspane').html("").html(datal);
      alert(datas);
    }
  });
});
```

Please help on this issue.

Comment: your code is doing an ajax request once when the document is ready. You asked for _"I want to pass data [..] information between tags with ajax on every click"_ but it's not clear. One way to read that could be that you mean to perform an ajax request using as input the data attribute of the element clicked when such event occurs. Anyway _"passing data between elements"_ is misleading. All I can say for sure it's better qualify your data attribute as something like `data-cmd` for example

Answer (score 0):

Your `datas` variable is out of scope for the ajax call. You are instanciating the variable on the click of the nav link, but the ajax call is running when the DOM is ready.

The following should give you what you want:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav-link').click(function() {
    var datas = $(this) attr("data");
    $.ajax({
      url: 'indextab.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { datas: datas },
      success: function(datal) {
        $('.tabspane').html("").html(datal);
        alert(datas);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: yes, that's it, thanks, but when it's not clicked, I want the new data to be retrieved.

Answer (score -1):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav-link').click(function() {
    var datas = $(this) attr("data");
    $.ajax({
      url: 'indextab.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { datas: datas },
      success: function(datal) {
        $('.tabspane').html("").html(datal);
        alert(datas);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

yes, that's it, thanks, but when it's not clicked, I want the new data to be retrieved